# Не рендерит обновление количества

Tags: reactjs, mobx

```
render() {
    return(
      <div onClick={()=>{
        this.props.store.count = this.props.store.count+1
        console.log(this.props.store.count)
      }}>
        {this.props.store.count}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не будет работать, нельзя менять свои пропсы, нужно сохранять пропс в локальный стейт и его уже менять:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const store = {
    count: 1
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Component store={store}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Component(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(props.store.count);
  function handleChange() {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }
  return (<>
    <p>count: {count}</p>
    <button onClick={handleChange}>+</button>
  </>)
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```